# Unmanaged method member being used as a delegate in managed class

Tags: callback, delegates, c++-cli, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a project where I am expanding existing native C++ compatible code functionality for a customer-facing library by integrating a driver from a managed DLL, which seems like the opposite direction for most marshaling questions.  Since there can be multiple devices using this one driver, each device needs to be its own object, with its own callback methods.  This integration will take the form of a native wrapper DLL that exposes the native class interface to the customer-facing library, which will pass an instance of a member method callback function pointer to the DLL.  I need to pass a native method member instance (non-static) as a delegate to the managed wrapper class.  The managed wrapper class uses GetDelegateForFunctionPointer, which works to marshal static native pointers to a delegate, but I can't find any information if it works with instances.  GetDelegateForFunctionPointer also takes a System::IntPtr argument for the function pointer, but I'm also not sure if System::IntPtr works for instances, and when compiling in VC++2008 I'm being presented an error C3867 for attempting this.

Managed wrapper header:

```
//somemanagedclass.hpp
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace ExternalManagedLibrary;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
   public ref class SomeManagedClass
   {
      public:
         SomeManagedClass();
         ~SomeManagedClass();

         delegate void CallbackHandler(const wchar_t*, int);
         CallbackHandler^ CallbackEvent;

         void RegisterCallback(IntPtr callbackEvent);

      private:
         ExternalManagedClass^ externalManagedClass;

         void OnCallback(Object^ sender, ValueEventArgs<String^>^ e);
   };
}
```

Managed wrapper source:

```
//somemanagedclass.cpp
#include "somemanagedclass.hpp"
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
   SomeManagedClass::SomeManagedClass()
   {
      externalManagedClass = gcnew ExternalManagedClass();
      externalManagedClass->CallbackEvent += gcnew EventHandler<ValueEventArgs<String^>^>(this, &SomeManagedClass::OnCallback);
   }

   SomeManagedClass::~SomeManagedClass()
   {
      externalManagedClass->CallbackEvent -= gcnew EventHandler<ValueEventArgs<String^>^>(this, &SomeManagedClass::OnCallback);
   }

   void SomeManagedClass::OnCallback(Object^ sender, ValueEventArgs<String^>^ e)
   {
      String^ some_string = String::Copy(e->Value);
      cli::pin_ptr<const wchar_t> pinned_string = &PtrToStringChars(some_string)[0];
      const wchar_t* p = pinned_string;

      CallbackEvent(pinned_string, some_string->Length);
   }

   void SomeManagedClass::RegisterCallback(IntPtr callbackEvent)
   {
      CallbackEvent = (CallbackHandler^)(Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callbackEvent, CallbackHandler::typeid));
   }
}
```

Native wrapper interface:

```
//somenativeinterface.hpp
#ifdef DLL_EXPORT
   #define IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif //DLL_EXPORT

typedef void (*NativeCallback)(const unsigned char*, unsigned long);

class IMPORT_EXPORT SomeNativeInterface
{
   public:
      //class factory
      static SomeNativeInterface* Create(void);
      static void Destroy(SomeNativeInterface* clInterface);

      virtual void CallbackInit(NativeCallback fnNativeCallbackInit);
};
```

Native wrapper header:

```
//somenativeclass.hpp
#pragma once

#include "somenativeinterface.hpp"
#include "somemanagedclass.hpp"
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace SomeNameSpace;

class IMPORT_EXPORT SomeNativeClass : public SomeNativeInterface
{
   public:
      SomeNativeClass();
      ~SomeNativeClass();

      void CallbackInit(NativeCallback fnNativeCallbackInit); //can this take an instance?

   private:
      NativeCallback fnNativeCallback;
      void OnNativeCallback(const wchar_t* cString, int iSize);
      gcroot<SomeManagedClass^> wrapper;   //warning C4251
};
```

Native wrapper source:

```
//somenativeclass.cpp
#include "somenativeclass.hpp"
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;

SomeNativeInterface* SomeNativeInterface::Create()
{
   return ((SomeNativeInterface*) new SomeNativeClass());
}

void SomeNativeInterface::Destroy(SomeNativeInterface* instance)
{
   delete instance;
}

SomeNativeClass::SomeNativeClass()
{
   wrapper = gcnew SomeManagedClass();
}

SomeNativeClass::OnNativeCallback(const wchar_t* cString, int iSize)
{
   std::auto_ptr<char> pcConvertedString(new char[iSize+1]);
   size_t iCharsConverted;
   if (wcstombs_s(&iCharsConverted, (char*)*pcConvertedString, iSize+1, cString, iSize) == 0)
   {
      if (iCharsConverted > 0xFFFFFFFF)
         iCharsConverted = 0xFFFFFFFF;   //truncate
      fnNativeCallback((const unsigned char*)*pcConvertedString, (unsigned long)(iCharsConverted));
   }
}

SomeNativeClass::CallbackInit(NativeCallback fnNativeCallbackInit)
{
   fnNativeCallback = fnNativeCallbackInit;
   wrapper->RegisterCallback(System::IntPtr(this->OnNativeCallback)); //error C3867
}
```

Comment: Show a small but complete representative example in code.